# configure: error: --with-ssl was given, but OpenSSL wasn't found on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, cross-compiling

I have try to compile and build libcurl inside my toolcahin folder by using cross compile but always I got same error...

1-First I build openssl by this steps

```
export TOOLCHAIN=/home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-7.5.0
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
export PATH="$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH"
./Configure linux-generic32 --prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr no-async
make depends
make
make install
.
.
.
cp libcrypto.pc /home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig
chmod 644 /home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
cp libssl.pc /home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig
chmod 644 /home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
cp openssl.pc /home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig
chmod 644 /home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
.
.
.
~/$ ls -n from gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 6 raed raed  4096 نوف 26 12:31 arm-linux-gnueabi
drwxr-xr-x 2 raed raed  4096 ديس  4  2019 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 raed raed 11287 ديس  4  2019 gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-linux-manifest.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3 raed raed  4096 ديس  4  2019 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 raed raed  4096 ديس  4  2019 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 raed raed  4096 ديس  4  2019 libexec
drwxr-xr-x 8 raed raed  4096 ديس  4  2019 share

~/$ ls -n from arm-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  2 raed raed 4096 نوف 26 12:18 bin
drwxr-xr-x 34 raed raed 4096 نوف 26 12:18 include
drwxr-xr-x  6 raed raed 4096 نوف 26 12:18 lib
drwxr-xr-x  3 raed raed 4096 ديس  4  2019 libexec
drwxr-xr-x  2 raed raed 4096 ديس  4  2019 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  5 raed raed 4096 ديس  4  2019 share
drwxrwxr-x  6 raed raed 4096 نوف 26 12:18 ssl
```

2-Then I have try to build libcurl with--ssl but I have got error

```
cd curl-7.72.0
export TOOLCHAIN=/home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-7.5.0
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
export PATH="$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH"
./configure --with-ssl=/home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr --host=arm-linux-gnueabi
.
.
.
configure: PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR will be set to "/home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for openssl options with pkg-config... found
configure: pkg-config: SSL_LIBS: "-lssl -lcrypto"
configure: pkg-config: SSL_LDFLAGS: "-L/home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib"
configure: pkg-config: SSL_CPPFLAGS: "-I/home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include"
checking for HMAC_Update in -lcrypto... no
checking for HMAC_Init_ex in -lcrypto... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl and -lpthread... no 
configure: OPT_SSL: /home/MY/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr
configure: OPENSSL_ENABLED: 
configure: error: --with-ssl was given but OpenSSL could not be detected
```

P.s: same steps work just fine on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to build `libcurl` with `openssl` support, and this may not be immediate to find out what is causing this issue.

But here is the procedure I am using on Ubuntu 20.04.1 - You may have to adjust the content of the `CROSS_COMPILE` variable, since you are using the `arm-linux-gnueabi` toolchain, and not the `arm-none-linux-gnueabihf` one: I am using the [gcc toolchain for Cortex-A](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads) from ARM.
The versions of `curl` and `openssl` may have to be adjusted as well.

```
CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-
PREFIX=$(pwd)/sysroot

wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz
tar zxf openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz
pushd openssl-1.1.1h
./Configure linux-generic32 shared  -DL_ENDIAN --prefix=${PREFIX} --openssldir=${PREFIX} shared
make CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf- PROCESSOR=ARM install
popd

wget https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
tar xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
pushd zlib-1.2.11
CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc ./configure --prefix=${PREFIX}
make CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc all install 
popd

wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.73.0.tar.gz
tar zxf curl-7.73.0.tar.gz
pushd curl-7.73.0
CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar NM=${CROSS_COMPILE}nm AS=${CROSS_COMPILE}as  ./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --with-ssl=${PREFIX} --prefix=${PREFIX} --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf --without-libidn2
make CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar NM=${CROSS_COMPILE}nm AS=${CROSS_COMPILE}as install
popd


ll -gG sysroot/lib/
total 6796
drwxrwxr-x 4    4096 Nov 16 08:10 ./
drwxrwxr-x 9    4096 Nov 16 07:53 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2    4096 Nov 16 07:53 engines-1.1/
-rw-r--r-- 1 3199974 Nov 16 07:53 libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      16 Nov 16 07:53 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 2087864 Nov 26 07:53 libcrypto.so.1.1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1    1027 Nov 26 08:10 libcurl.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1      16 Nov 26 08:10 libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.7.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1      16 Nov 26 08:10 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.7.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  407748 Nov 26 08:10 libcurl.so.4.7.0*
-rw-r--r-- 1  578076 Nov 26 07:53 libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      13 Nov 26 07:53 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  453684 Nov 26 07:53 libssl.so.1.1*
-rw-r--r-- 1   96210 Nov 26 07:51 libz.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      14 Nov 26 07:51 libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1      14 Nov 26 07:51 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11*
-rwxr-xr-x 1   98708 Nov 26 07:51 libz.so.1.2.11*
drwxrwxr-x 2    4096 Nov 26 08:10 pkgconfig/

file sysroot/bin/curl
sysroot/bin/curl: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped           

share edit delete flag
```

Comment: Thank you for answer .. But I have got same error with arm-none-linux-gnueabihf also .. configure: error: --with-ssl was given but OpenSSL could not be detected

Comment: As explained in my answer, my goal was to provide you with a working procedure. You are of course free not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when cross compiling **libcurl** with **Buildroot**.

I found a temporary fix, described below.

The error is caused by a failed test for OpenSSL features, in the libcurl **configure** script.

```
output/build/libcurl-7.78.0/configure
```

I found the error in the **config.log** file for libcurl:

```
output/build/libcurl-7.78.0/config.log
```

(Search for "**HMAC_Update in -lcrypto**", the test where the error first occurs)

The error message was:

**arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc: ERROR: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '-I/usr/include'**

An incorrect include path is obtained by the configure script from the openssl pkgconfig file from the `STAGING_DIR`:

```
output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
```

This appears to be a bug in the configure script.

## Temporary Fix:

Edit the configure script:

```
output/build/libcurl-7.78.0/configure
```

and search for "**HMAC_Update in -lcrypto**". It should be in a line that looks like:  `{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for HMAC_Update in -lcrypto" >&5 $as_echo_n "checking for HMAC_Update in -lcrypto... " >&6; }`

Immediately above it are the two lines:

```
CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS $SSL_CPPFLAGS"
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $SSL_LDFLAGS"
```

Comment out these two lines, like so:

```
#CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS $SSL_CPPFLAGS"
#LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $SSL_LDFLAGS"
```

Now the compilation should succeed.

This fix may not work in all cases.

I have not verified if libcurl works after this, but it compiles successfully.

Comment: Doesn't fix it on Mac OS 12.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ..
I solve the issue ...
The problem is with zlib need to build it inside toolchain and add this in configure seetings

`--with-zlib=$prefix/lib`